# Can we use dynamic array data() as a longopts parameter in getopt_long function?

Tags: c++, getopt-long

I am trying to create an argument parsing class on C++ that will be using `getopt_long` function.
So basically I want the `longopts` argument can be created dynamically.

This code, that using static array for `longopts` argument will work:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  while (true) {
    static struct option long_options_static[] = {
      {"a", required_argument, 0, 'a'},
      {"b", required_argument, 0, 'b'},
    };
    int option_index = 0;
    char c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "", long_options_static, &option_index);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But this, that using `std::vector` will compile but not work as expected:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  while (true) {
    std::vector<struct option> long_options_vect(2);
    long_options_vec[0] = {"a", required_argument, 0, 'a'};
    long_options_vec[1] = {"b", required_argument, 0, 'b'};
    int option_index = 0;
    char c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "", long_options_vect.data(), &option_index);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

From the `getopt_long` [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long), it only stated that

> longopts is a pointer to the first element of an array of struct option...

So in theory, using any kind of containers such as std::vector or std::array and then passing the storage's pointer is possible right?
But I get `unrecognized option` error, am I missing something?

Comment: Doesn’t the array need to include a special sentinel value to indicate its end?  Otherwise, `getopt_long` cannot know how many elements are in the array. From the linked man page: *The last element of the array has to be filled with zeros.*

Comment: I see, I missed that one. Now it's working. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The array needs to include a special sentinel value to indicate its end. Otherwise, `getopt_long` cannot know how many elements are in the array. From the linked man page:

> The last element of the array has to be filled with zeros.